# Storing character into buffer based on offset not working

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am working on a program that takes an input of a number, and outputs it in base 10, 2, 4, and 8. The logic to get the number from input was simple enough, as well as the conversion of such number given a base. The part that I'm stuck on requires to store the converted number into a buffer which at the end is read using `TRAP x22`

This is my idea:

- First I would load the address for the block of space (FINNUM) into R5
- Also load the BUFFER (x0000, to attempt to stop the output) into R6
- Store R6 into R5 to get the null terminator
- Decrement R5
- Load the first value of DIGITS into another register, R4
- Then execute the division
- Add R4 and R3 (offset for R4) into R6
- Store R6 again into R5 to store the obtained value
- Decrement R5
- Do the proper algorithm checking (if the quotient was zero then no more division, exit out of loop)
- Put R5 into R0
- Output

I tried doing what I described in the code below, but I get gibberish for output (and curiously enough the whole DIGITS string) What is it that I'm not checking here? Obviously the storage operation is not working, but I don't see why it is not. Please let me know where I could start fixing this error.

```
;Subroutine PRINT*************************************************************
;Displays an unsigned integer in any base up to 16, e.g. binary, octal, decimal
;Parameters - R0: the integer - R1: the base
PRINT
    ST  R0, PR0
    ST  R1, PR1
    ST  R2, PR2
    ST  R3, PR3
    ST  R4, PR4
    ST  R5, PR5
    ST  R6, PR6
    ST  R7, PR7 

    LEA R5, FINNUM  ;Prepare pointer to storage
    LEA R6, BUFFER
    STR R6, R5, #0
    ADD R5, R5, #-1
    LD  R4, DIGITS  ;Prepare pointer to the digits  
SDIV
    JSR DIVIDE      
    ADD R6, R4, R3  ;Add the remainder with digits to get number
    STR R6, R5, #0  ;Store number into buffer
    ADD R5, R5, #-1 ;Decrement
    ADD R0, R2, #0  ;Pass quotient into R0
    BRP SDIV        ;If number is at least 1, then divide again

    ADD R0, R5, #0  ;If we got here, then we should have the converted number
    TRAP    x22     ;Last but not least we display

    LD  R7, PR7
    RET
;Data
DIGITS  .STRINGZ "0123456789ABCDEF" ;Digits
FINNUM  .BLKW   18          ;Output Buffer
BUFFER  .FILL   x0000           ;Null
PR0 .BLKW   1
PR1 .BLKW   1
PR2 .BLKW   1
PR3 .BLKW   1
PR4 .BLKW   1
PR5 .BLKW   1
PR6 .BLKW   1
PR7 .BLKW   1
```

Should you need it, here is the code for the remaining of the program:

```
.ORIG   x3000
    LEA R0, MPROMPT
    TRAP    x22
LOOP
    JSR GETDEC      ;Input an unsigned (decimal) integer
    ADD R0, R0, #0  ;Exit if the input integer is 0
    BRZ EXIT

    JSR NEWLN       ;Move cursor to the start of a new line
    AND R1, R1, #0  ;R1 = 10 (output base 10 DECIMAL)
    ADD R1, R1, #10 
    JSR PRINT       ;Print the integer in decimal

    JSR NEWLN       ;Move cursor to the start of a new line
    AND R1, R1, #0  ;R1 = 2 (output base 2 BINARY)
    ADD R1, R1, #2
    JSR PRINT       ;Print the integer in binary

    JSR NEWLN       ;Move cursor to the start of a new line
    AND R1, R1, #0  ;R1 = 8 (output base 8 OCTAL)
    ADD R1, R1, #8
    JSR PRINT       ;Print the integer in octal

    JSR NEWLN       ;Move cursor to the start of a new line
    AND R1, R1, #0  ;R1 = 16 (output base 16 HEXADECIMAL)
    ADD R1, R1, #15
    ADD R1, R1, #1
    JSR PRINT       ;Print the integer in hexadecimal

    JSR NEWLN       ;Move cursor to the start of a new line

    BRNZP   LOOP
EXIT                ;Loop exit point
    TRAP    x25     ;HALT program execution
MPROMPT .STRINGZ "Enter a sequence of unsigned integer values\nEnter 0 To Quit\n"

;Subroutine NEWLN*************************************************************
;Advances the console cursor to the start of a new line
NEWLN   
    ST  R7, NEW7    ;Save working registers
    ST  R0, NEW0

    LD  R0, NL      ;Output a newline character
    TRAP    x21

    LD  R0, NEW0    ;Restore working registers
    LD  R7, NEW7
    RET         ;Return
;Data
NL  .FILL   x000A   ;Newline character
NEW0    .BLKW   1   ;Save area - R0
NEW7    .BLKW   1   ;Save area - R7

;Subroutine GETDEC************************************************************
;Inputs an unsigned integer typed at the console in decimal format
;The input value is returned in R0
GETDEC
    ;Save Values of ALL Registers that don't need to change
    ST  R1, GET1
    ST  R2, GET2
    ST  R3, GET3
    ST  R4, GET4
    ST  R5, GET5
    ST  R6, GET6
    ST  R7, GET7    ;Save R7 to be able to return to main

    AND R3, R3, #0  ;Prepare a value
    LEA R0, GPROMPT
    TRAP    x22
GETDKEY
    TRAP    x20     ;To input a keystroke   
    ADD R2, R0, #-10    ;Subtract new keystroke by 10 (new line, or enter)
    BRZ GFINIS      ;If R2 is 0 we just pressed enter, so we break out
    TRAP    x21     ;Echo keystroke     
    ADD R2, R0, #0  ;Get the number back
    AND R2, R2, #15 ;We mask to only get the first four bits
    ADD R3, R3, R3  ;1st addition: x + x = 2x
    ADD R4, R3, #0  ;Store the 2x
    ADD R3, R3, R3  ;2nd addition: 2x + 2x = 4x
    ADD R3, R3, R3  ;3rd addition: 4x + 4x = 8x
    ADD R3, R3, R4  ;4th addition: 8x + 2x = 10x
    ADD R3, R3, R2  ;10x + new number
    BRNZP   GETDKEY     ;Go back to get next number
GFINIS
    ADD R0, R3, #0  ;Put number into R0

    ;Restore the values of registers that don't need change
    LD  R1, GET7
    LD  R2, GET7
    LD  R3, GET7
    LD  R4, GET7
    LD  R5, GET7
    LD  R6, GET7
    LD  R7, GET7    ;Get back the value of R7
    RET
;Data
GPROMPT .STRINGZ "Enter an unsigned integer> "  ;Input Prompt
GET1    .BLKW   1
GET2    .BLKW   1
GET3    .BLKW   1
GET4    .BLKW   1
GET5    .BLKW   1
GET6    .BLKW   1
GET7    .BLKW   1

;Subroutine PRINT*************************************************************
;Displays an unsigned integer in any base up to 16, e.g. binary, octal, decimal
;Parameters - R0: the integer - R1: the base
PRINT
    ST  R0, PR0
    ST  R1, PR1
    ST  R2, PR2
    ST  R3, PR3
    ST  R4, PR4
    ST  R5, PR5
    ST  R6, PR6
    ST  R7, PR7 

    LEA R5, FINNUM  ;Prepare pointer to storage
    LEA R6, BUFFER
    STR R6, R5, #0
    ADD R5, R5, #-1
    LD  R4, DIGITS  ;Prepare pointer to the digits  
SDIV
    JSR DIVIDE      
    ADD R6, R4, R3  ;Add the remainder with digits to get number
    STR R6, R5, #0  ;Store number into buffer
    ADD R5, R5, #-1 ;Decrement
    ADD R0, R2, #0  ;Pass quotient into R0
    BRP SDIV        ;If number is at least 1, then divide again

    ADD R0, R5, #0  ;If we got here, then we should have the converted number
    TRAP    x22     ;Last but not least we display

    LD  R7, PR7
    RET
;Data
DIGITS  .STRINGZ "0123456789ABCDEF" ;Digits
FINNUM  .BLKW   18          ;Output Buffer
BUFFER  .FILL   x0000           ;Null
PR0 .BLKW   1
PR1 .BLKW   1
PR2 .BLKW   1
PR3 .BLKW   1
PR4 .BLKW   1
PR5 .BLKW   1
PR6 .BLKW   1
PR7 .BLKW   1

;Subroutine DIVIDE************************************************************
;Perform unsigned integer division to obtain Quotient and Remainder
;Parameters (IN)  : R0 - Numerator,  R1 - Divisor
;Parameters (OUT) : R2 - Quotient,   R3 - Remainder
DIVIDE  
    ST  R5, DIV7
    ST  R6, DIV7
    ST  R7, DIV7

    AND R2, R2, #0
    ADD R3, R0, #0
    ADD R5, R1, #0
    NOT R5, R5
    ADD R5, R5, #1 ;2's complement to R5 to be able to substract    
DSUBT
    ADD R6, R3, R5 ;R6 = R3 - R5
    BRN ENDDIV
    ADD R2, R2, #1 ;If here, R0 was bigger than R1, we can add 1
    ADD R3, R3, R5 ;Subtract again to avoid losing the remainder
    BRNZP   DSUBT
ENDDIV  
    LD  R5, DIV7
    LD  R6, DIV7
    LD  R7, DIV7
    RET        ;Return
;Data
DIV7    .BLKW   1

    .END
```

This is something that I could do in Java with my eyes closed, but I am too new to this language and frankly am still trying to understand problems with storing registers prior to the function execution and loading them back at the end. I mention this because it has caused me problems with getting the input (i.e. going back to main execution) and in division. Please let me know, and thank you for any help in advance

**EDIT:** Changed the function to start at `BUFFER` address, added 18 to get to last available storage space, then modified storing process to first decrement then store. Also, all registers are stored at beginning then reloaded at the end, just in case:

```
;Subroutine PRINT*************************************************************
;Displays an unsigned integer in any base up to 16, e.g. binary, octal, decimal
;Parameters - R0: the integer - R1: the base
PRINT
    ST  R0, PR0
    ST  R1, PR1
    ST  R2, PR2
    ST  R3, PR3
    ST  R4, PR4
    ST  R5, PR5
    ST  R6, PR6
    ST  R7, PR7 

    LEA R6, FINNUM
    ADD R6, R6, #10 ;Add to get to the end of the buffer
    ADD R6, R6, #8  ;Add to get to the end of the buffer
    AND R5, R5, #0  ;To make sure R5 is cleared
    LD  R4, DIGITS  ;Prepare pointer to the digits  
SDIV
    JSR DIVIDE      
    ADD R5, R4, R3  ;Add the remainder with digits to get number
    ADD R6, R6, #-1 ;Decrement to get to the next one
    STR R5, R6, #0  ;Store number into buffer
    ADD R0, R2, #0  ;Pass quotient into R0
    BRP SDIV        ;If number is at least 1, then divide again

    ADD R0, R6, #0  ;If we got here, then we should have the converted number
    TRAP    x22     ;Last but not least we display

    LD  R0, PR0
    LD  R1, PR1
    LD  R2, PR2
    LD  R3, PR3
    LD  R4, PR4
    LD  R5, PR5
    LD  R6, PR6
    LD  R7, PR7
    RET
;Data
DIGITS  .STRINGZ "0123456789ABCDEF" ;Digits
FINNUM  .BLKW   18          ;Output Buffer
BUFFER  .FILL   x0000           ;Null
PR0 .BLKW   1
PR1 .BLKW   1
PR2 .BLKW   1
PR3 .BLKW   1
PR4 .BLKW   1
PR5 .BLKW   1
PR6 .BLKW   1
PR7 .BLKW   1
```

The LC3 stops at `ADD   R0, R2, #0`, right after the `STR`. Is it that the program is not storing in the appropriate place?

Comment: Since you are writing backwards, you should set your pointer to the last location initially. Also, `LEA R6, BUFFER` loads the address of `BUFFER` (which is a terrible name by the way) and storing that makes no sense. PS: learn to use your debugger/simulator to step through the code.

Comment: I did as you suggested and simplified my function a little (please see edit), but now the program halts by itself right after the `STR` command. I checked the register values in the LC3 and these are correct, so would it be the memory address that's wrong? I know you said storing `BUFFER` makes no sense, but I'm supposed to do that as per assignment instructions. If you know, please just give me a hint, I am honestly not trying to have someone else do my coding hw of all things for me

Comment: Because you use bad naming I can't really tell what's wrong. For some reason you call your output buffer `FINNUM` and no idea what `BUFFER` is for except storing a zero. Adding 18 to that makes no sense. If you are writing into `FINNUM` (where you actually have space, and the comment says that's for the output) you need to add the 18 to that and write there.

Comment: I can't change the `BUFFER` because that's how the incomplete code was given to me, but `FINNUM` is supposed to mean the final number to display at the end. I changed my code to load the effective address starting at `FINNUM`, the BLKW, but the error persists

Comment: One other issue, your `DIVIDE` is storing `R5`-`R7` into the same `DIV7` variable.

Comment: I guess that's the downside of coming from a high level language background, it's harder for me to find these errors. I added BLKW for both DIV5 and DIV6 and the program now works for decimal and binary conversion, but not for hex. I'll keep working on that, but thank you very much for all your help and for bearing with me